# Engines that play Mangala?

Tags: mancala

[Mangala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mangala_(game)) is the Turkish version of mancala, with its own set of rules.

I am planning on doing a project in it. Are there any game engines that either specifically play it, or universal Mancala players that plays it after supplying the options?

EDIT:

I am not looking for an app, but for a game engine. For example in chess, [Deep Shredder](http://www.shredderchess.com/chess-software/deep-shredder12.html) is a playing app, while [Stockfish](http://stockfishchess.org/) is an open-source engine.

Comment: Stackoverexchange is not google. You are expected to do your own research.

Comment: I didn't find anything usable

Comment: @ColinD Referring others to Google is not constructive, and lack of research is not a valid reason to close a question. Just hover over the downvote button and a tooltip will appear that describes what it is for, in case you have forgotten. To others (not Colin), if *"Where can I find a Mangala client?"* is off topic, then [*"Where can I find an MTG client?"*](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7267/6692) is definitely off topic as well. Try to be consistent.

Comment: @Rainbolt, The difference between the 2 questions is that the MTG one is clearly about playing the game, this seems to be more about simulating the game play.

Comment: @ColinD I want to use it for both. I am the top player on my school, and want to do a project for an upcoming fair.

Comment: Voting to reopen: the close reason says "except for computer-based versions of board or card games" which is exactly what this question is about. Maybe it's off-topic for some other reason, but no one has bothered to explain why.

Comment: @Jefromi I agree with you. We should place this on the meta.

Comment: This is a year old so what did you end up doing? Did you find an engine or did you write your own?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the name is correct. [Here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mangala/id582929998?mt=8) is Mangala game available on the AppStore. I haven't played it, so I can't confirm that it's using Turkish variant of the rules rather than the most popular one from Mancala.

I guess we have to wait until you introduce a playable game of Mangala! :) Of course if that's what your project is about.

You could specify in your question (list) what rules are important to you to be included in the version you're looking for. Take a look [here](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/173916/item/3238672#item3238672), maybe one of those games is similar enough.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found what you're looking for. If you're really willing to do this project, I found a Google Play Turkish Mangala game, I hope it's what you're looking for. Although, you can just buy a board online, or somewhere.

[Turkish Mangala](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamesanatolian.mangala&hl=en) - if this doesn't work use this: [Turkish Puzzle Game](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mangala/id582929998?mt=8)

Comment: Welcome to BC&G! :) I believe the link you used is the same I've provided in my answer and the other one is Android version.

Comment: I used to have this on my computer before phone apps. It was called Bantumi. Also try looking for Kalah